# Use bitwise AND on an int in C++

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

My question is simple: how do I perform a bitwise AND on an `int` in C++?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned int foo = 3;
    unsigned int bar = 6;
    std::cout << foo & bar;
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of outputting 2, it prints 3.

When I do any other bitwise operation, it also just prints the first variable.

How do I get it to do the operation?

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Your expression is simply seen as `(std::cout << foo) & bar;` If you turn up your warning levels high enough you would see something along the lines of "result of expression unused"

Comment: I'm curious which compiler actually compiled this. GCC and Clang trunk do not, nor does the version of MSVC on Compiler Explorer.

Comment: @chris I used the default one on Eclipse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add parentheses around your `foo & bar` because the `&` operator has a lower precedence than the shift `<<` operator.

```
std::cout << (foo & bar);
```

As a side note, I am surprised that the code compiles without the parentheses. Bonus: the doc for operator precedence rules on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: You are a great person.

Comment: @Field-os, Give  Rerito some sweet sweet reputation points and mark his answer as accepted if it solves your problem

Comment: @Spoonless I have to wait 10 minutes before I can.